# .net mvc - class method calling a method of caller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class

.NET MVC application. In a controller action, I create an instance of ClientsService class, then call its method A(). This method creates an instance of another class, then call one of its method, but that method needs to call a method of clientsService... How can this be done correctly?

```
Namespace MyApp.Services

public class ClientsService 
{
    ApplicationDbContext db;

    public ClientsService(ApplicationDbContext db) 
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void A() 
    {
        int x = 5;
        var instance = new SomeOtherClass(db)
        instance.SomeMethod(x);
    }

    //returns object type name
    public string getObjectTypeName(object obj) 
    {
        return ObjectContext.GetObjectType(obj.GetType()).Name;
    }
}


public class SomeOtherClass() 
{
    ApplicationDbContext db;

    public SomeOtherClass(ApplicationDbContext db) 
    {
        this.db = db;
    }
    public void SomeMethod(int i)
    {
        /////////////////
        //I NEED TO CALL getObjectTypeName() HERE!!
        /////////////////
    }
}
```

probably the method getObjectTypeName() should not reside on that class, but on some kind of global class (as it may be used anywhere)? If so, how should I do it? or maybe I could just pass the ClientsService instance itself to the method in SomeOtherClass? (something like instance.SomeMethod(db, this))?

I am lost here, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass an instance of your object `ClientsService` inside `SomeOtherClass`.

```
public SomeOtherClass(ClientsService service, ApplicationDbContext db) 
{
    this.service = service;
    this.db = db;
}

public void SomeMethod(int i)
{
    this.service.getObjectTypeName();
}
```

I would suggest reading more on Dependency Injection to make the whole process of management dependencies more robust and easier to understand.

Comment: nice, so then I would create the instance with `new SomeOtherClass(this, db);`, right?